# IAM policy to force enable Aurora Read Replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I'd like to enforce IAM user when create Aurora Postgres cluster, they have to stick "Create an Aurora Replica or Reader node in a different AZ" in Multi-AZ deployment option. So I create IAM policy

```
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "rds:CreateDBCluster",
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "rds:MultiAZ": [
            "false"
          ]
        }
      }
```

But this policy not work as expected, the user can create Aurora Postgresql without enable multi-az deployment, is there something wrong?

Comment: " this policy not work as expected" is not clear. What **exactly** is happening?

Comment: @Marcin it not effect, the IAM user can create Aurora Postgresql without enable "Create an Aurora replica...", so the policy not correct

Answer (score 0):

AWS support said that IAM policy not support for enforce Multi-AZ deployment.